# Future is not Send, only when from async Trait

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Serializer`:

```rust
trait Serializer {
    fn serialize(&self, data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error>;
}
```

And some `Foo` which implements it. Notably, `data` is not `Send`.

The actual implementation requires an async context to execute, so I've split the creation of an async runtime away from the actual implementation, like so:

```rust
struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    async fn async_serialize(&self, _data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl Serializer for Foo {
    fn serialize(&self, data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let runtime = Builder::new_current_thread().enable_all().build().unwrap();
        runtime.block_on(async move { self.async_serialize(data).await })
    }
}
```

This compiles and works how I would expect.

- Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04171e7fb65a9e158903978fd19ef8ac

If I refactor the code such that the async Runtime creation is done by way of a trait:

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait AsyncSerializer {
    async fn async_serialize(&self, data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl AsyncSerializer for Foo {
    async fn async_serialize(&self, _data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

This does not compile, now complaining that `Rc<()>` isn't `Send`:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:19:73
   |
19 |       async fn async_serialize(&self, _data: Rc<()>) -> Result<(), Error> {
   |  _________________________________________________________________________^
20 | |         unimplemented!();
21 | |     }
   | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<()>`
note: captured value is not `Send`
```

- Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23f61162b5be8384092888635d8daacc

This error message makes sense to me, `Rc` is not `Send`, but:

- Why was this not a problem before? The prior implementations (`impl on Foo` versus `impl AsyncSerializer for Foo`) look analogous to me.
- Can I wrap `data` in some way to avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell the compiler a value is not used after awaiting in an async\_trait method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650104/how-to-tell-the-compiler-a-value-is-not-used-after-awaiting-in-an-async-trait-me)

Comment: Also: [Why does one of these two very similar async Rust functions trigger thread safety errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69694548/7884305),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that `#[async_trait]` de-sugars your code requires your futures to be send, as explained [here](https://docs.rs/async-trait/0.1.53/async_trait/#explanation). To fix that change the attribute macro to be `#[async_trait(?Send)]`.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me why this was. I'd direct anyone who wondered the same to this blog post which explains some of the difficulties associated with async traits: https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/10/26/async-fn-in-traits-are-hard/

Notably: " ...because a `dyn Future` [return type] hides the underlying future (that is, indeed, its entire purpose), it also blocks the auto trait mechanism from figuring out if the result is `Send`"