# future not send with async Trait in rust

Tags: rust

I worked on a async trait with async_trait

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait UserRepo {

     async fn init() -> Result<Self, AppError> ;

}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct UserRepoImpl {
    pub collection: mongodb::Collection<User>,
}

#[async_trait] 
impl  UserRepo for UserRepoImpl {

    pub async fn init() -> Result<Self, AppError>  { 

        let db = database::connection().await;
        let col: Collection<User> = db.collection("users");

        Ok(Auth{collection: col})
    }
```

compiling the code gives the error :

```
expected signature `fn() -> Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<UserRepoImpl, AppError>> + std::marker::Send + 'async_trait)>>`
              found signature `fn() -> Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<UserRepoImpl, AppError>> + 'async_trait)>>
```

how would I solve this ?

Comment: Please add the complete error message from the compiler (`cargo build`), not your IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future is not Send, only when from async Trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72341910/future-is-not-send-only-when-from-async-trait)